AwesomeWM config not working correctly
I have a issue with this config https://github.com/HikariKnight/material-awesome?tab=readme-ov-file that is distro specific to Ubuntu, When I expand a menu in the master branch of awesome with this config everything including windows and nav bars dissapear. I think maybe some dependencies are unmet. I am using Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS Ubuntu Mate flavour.

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details; please tell us what Ubuntu product you're using; Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? a flavor of Ubuntu? and which release.  A quick look at the page you provided and details are rather OLD/outdated, so release will be very critical

Thank you for telling me, next time i write a question i will make sure that will be included. I have also edited the question. Thank you lots.

If you're using Ubuntu MATE 24.04 LTS just say so, as Ubuntu Desktop uses the GNOME desktop & varies somewhat in software stack when compared with MATE used by Ubuntu MATE.  Ubuntu-MATE is on-topic on this site being an official flavor; MATE & GNOME have different WMs & defaults.

This issue also persists in any flavour of ubuntu its not flavour specific. Including the normal Gnome desktop.

Also asked at https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/awesomewm-config-not-working-correctly/28130   ; issue is software stack related & not desktop specific.. ie. the page its from was from years ago & thus config I'd expect to need tweaking for newer (24.04) systems...

Alright I'll try tweaking with the config, Thank you all lots for the help.
